# get the index of tr after filter of td text jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var indexoftr = $("#table tbody tr td:nth-child(1)").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == name;
}).get().closest("tr").index();
```

I want to get the index of tr of the `td` if the name is matching my requirement i have the above code but i am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).filter(...).get(...).closest is not a function

How to properly get the `index` of parent `tr` of matching `td` text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `get()` returns native array which doesn't have `.closest()` method thus you are getting the error.

Just remove `get()`

```js
var indexoftr = $("#table tbody tr td:nth-child(1)").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == name;
}).closest("tr").index();
```

Comment: I see. that was the solution. give me a few minutes to tick the answer.